# How to send XML data through body to node js server using fetch method

Tags: node.js

I am trying to send the XML data to node server using fetch method but I am not able get that data in node API. I am able to give API call through fetch. Below is code for fetch method.

The `(result.value)` contains the XML data

```
  fetch('http://localhost:1000/api/Base64', {
          mode: 'no-cors',
          method: 'POST',    
          body:JSON.stringify(result.value),
          headers: new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'}),
        })
          .then(response => {
            return response
            console.log(response);
          }
          ).then(data => {
            console.log(data);
          }).catch(err=>{console.log('errr handled in',err)})
```

The Node.js API is as follows

```
  export const Base64 = async (req, res) => {
            console.log(req.body);       
        res.status(200).send({ msg: 'done' });
    };
```

The req.body shows empty.

Also not able to get the response message sent from Node.js API in fetch method.

Comment: To read the json message from server, use `response.json()` function. It will return a promise of data. Try with this minimalistic [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#uploading_json_data). If issue remains, you may need to give more information on your server implementation.

Comment: Assuming you're using Express, are you using the proper middleware to handle JSON request data?

Comment: XML data? You are sending a stringified JSON and setting content-type to `application/json` And even if that is what you want to do, do you have a respective middleware at the server, that parses the body back to JSON?